# Set HTML snippet's visibility depending on radio button value

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to make a bit of html, e.g. `<p>Only visible if almond checked</p>`, visible only when the radio button with `value="almond"` is checked.

Here's what I've tried. The view:

```html
<p>Send me spam: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: wantsSpam" /></p>
<p>Only visible if almond checked</p>
<div data-bind="visible: wantsSpam">
    Preferred flavor of spam:
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Cherry</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Almond</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>
```

And this view model:

```
 var viewModel = {
        wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
        spamFlavor: ko.observable("almond")
    };

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

See also [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyn8/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be this:

```html
<p data-bind="visible: spamFlavor() === 'almond'">Only visible if almond checked</p>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyn8/7/).

Typically you want to move the `spamFlavor() == 'almond'` bit to a seperate view model property with some meaning though. Maybe something like this:

```html
<p data-bind="visible: almondSpecialVisible">Only visible if almond checked</p>
```

With view model:

```
viewModel.almondSpecialVisible = ko.computed(function() { 
    return viewModel.spamFlavor() == 'almond'; 
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyn8/8/).